# Grabbing text from a page then validating it against an API call

Tags: cypress

I'm looking to intercept an API call, grab some values out of it then check that all the values are showing on the page.

I'm able to intercept the API call and perform checks against it. I'm able to grab the text from the page however I don't seem to be able to validate one against the other.

```
it('Check dashboard stats', () => {
    cy.intercept('GET', 'api/dashboard/kpi').as('kpi')

    cy.visit('/dashboard')
    cy.get('[data-cy=incomeThisMonthValue]').invoke('text').as('incomeThisMonth')
    cy.get('[data-cy=bookingsThisMonthValue]').invoke('text').as('bookingsThisMonth')
    cy.get('[data-cy=newCustomerThisMonthValue]').invoke('text').as('newCustomersThisMonth')

    cy.get('@kpi').should(({ response }) => {
      expect(response.body).to.have.property('success', true)
      cy.log(cy.get('@bookingsThisMonth'))
    })
  })
});
```

The `cy.log(cy.get('@bookingsThisMonth'))` displays an object in the console and not the text like I was expecting. I'm not sure how to get access to the text inside the `.should` to validate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract the text like this:

```js
cy.get('@kpi').should(({response}) => {
  expect(response.body).to.have.property('success', true)
  cy.get('@bookingsThisMonth').then((bookingsThisMonth) => {
    cy.log(bookingsThisMonth) //prints the value
    expect(response.body.bookings).to.equal(bookingsThisMonth)
  })
})
```